# Proper way to set permissions on an external disk's ext3 partition

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, permissions, mount, ext3

I have a new external disk and just made an ext3 partition on it. I'm wondering what's the best way to set permissions on it (so that it's rw for certain users). I guess I could `chmod ... /dev/sdb1` but I was thinking of a more dynamic way (kind of like `uid=` and `gid=` options for `vfat` and such).

Comment: there are no *uid=* or *gid=* mount options for ext3.  you'd configure permissions like you would for any other shared directory on the system -- make it owned by one group, and add all users to that group, or *chmod* the whole disk to 777, or use ACLs, or some other solution.

Comment: the trouble comes when you move this external ext3 drive to another system; if users/UIDs/groups/GIDs aren't synced across the two systems, you could end up with trouble -- files are owned by UIDs and GIDS, not users and groups.  this is what makes ext3 troublesome for external disks.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this would've been perfectly fine as an answer btw.